# Oracle date data type problem - I get wrong format as result in table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to set a column with date data type TO_TIMESTAMP to correct format to insert some data with merge into declaration.

The table.column = settings.data
The insert value as example: '28.01.2022 14:07'
But column is set as TIMESTAMP(6) format.
So need this to insert as: '28.01.2022 14:07:00,000000'

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE settings_import
(
in_id IN NUMBER
in_data IN TIMESTAMP
)
IS
BEGIN
MERGE INTO settings a
using (select in_id AS ID, in_data AS data from dual) b
on (a.ID = b.ID)
when not matched
then
INSERT into settings (ID, data) values (ID, data)
when matched
update set a.data = b.data
END settings_import;
BEGIN
settings_import (12, '28.01.2022 14:07');
END;
/
```

When I try this I get in column data this entry, but it's wrong: 28.01.2020 22:14:07,000000
right should be: '28.01.2022 14:07:00,000000'

When I try in the values (b.ID, TO_TIMESTAMP(b.data, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')
I get this error: **ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string**

How can I fix this? thank you!

Comment: Your `to_timestamp` with `HH24:MI:SS.FF` is failing because your input isn't providing anything after `HH24:MI`. What `to_char` format string did you apply when checking the value after the insert? What does `select to_char(a.data, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') from settings a;` return?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many, many syntax errors (missing commas, missing semi-colons, missing keywords, extra keywords)... If you fix those then:

`'28.01.2022 14:07'` is not a `TIMESTAMP` data type it is a string literal.

Either use a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```sql
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE settings_import(
    in_id   IN SETTINGS.ID%TYPE,
    in_data IN SETTINGS.DATA%TYPE
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO settings a
    USING DUAL
    ON (a.ID = in_id)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (ID, data) values (in_ID, in_data)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET a.data = in_data;
  END settings_import;
BEGIN
  settings_import (
    12,
    TIMESTAMP '2022-01-28 14:07:00'
  );
END;
/
```

Or explicitly use `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE settings_import(
    in_id   IN SETTINGS.ID%TYPE,
    in_data IN SETTINGS.DATA%TYPE
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO settings a
    USING DUAL
    ON (a.ID = in_id)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (ID, data) values (in_ID, in_data)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET a.data = in_data;
  END settings_import;
BEGIN
  settings_import (
    12,
    TO_TIMESTAMP('28.01.2022 14:07', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI')
  );
END;
/
```

Which, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE settings (id NUMBER, data TIMESTAMP);
```

Both will give a table with the value (with the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` of `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF`):

> | ID | DATA |
> | --- | --- |
> | 12 | 2022-01-28 14:07:00.000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b32524043df4ce68c3d2efca05296381)*

Answer (score 0):

I've had some syntax error as I wanted to simplify my code for better understanding, sorry, see below the corrected code which now works.

Thanks pmdba & MT0!

```
DECLARE 
PROCEDURE settings_import 
( 
in_id IN NUMBER, 
in_data IN varchar2 
) 
IS 
BEGIN 
MERGE INTO settings a 
using (select in_id AS ID, in_data AS data from dual) b 
on (a.ID = b.ID) 
when not matched 
then 
INSERT (ID, data) values (b.id, to_timestamp(b.data, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')) 
when matched 
then 
update set a.data = to_timestamp(b.data, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'); 
END settings_import; 
BEGIN 
settings_import (12, '11/11/2022 14:07'); 
 
END;
/
```